# Detecting subscription details when restoring in-app purchase

Tags: in-app-purchase, ios13, restore, in-app-subscription

Normally I sort out and investigate my coding issues, however, this one has stumped me and I have spent a day trawling through stackoverflow, github, youtube, apple developer documentation to no avail.

I have written an app in xcode v13, IoS 13, and the app has in-app purchases.  For in-app purchases I have 2 auto-renewing subscriptions, one for a monthly subscription, the other for an annual subscription.  I am testing the restore process which works fine.  I have used standard apple code.  However, what I am trying to do is establish/detect which service is being restored ie. suppose the use signs up for the annual subscription then when the in-app restore is done I am trying to detect that the user restore is for the annual subscription as opposed to the monthly subscription.

As I say I am struggling and have tried many many things but to no avail.  Has anyone else done this and if so are you able to give any pointers as to how you do it??

Thanking everyone in advance for guidance if you've done this before...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after spending a day trawling through many sources and getting nowhere, I stumbled across a little nugget from 2015 which has resolved the issue.  To recap - what I am trying to do is ascertain "which" in-app purchase subscription a customer has previously purchased that is being restored so that I can tune the scene / UI to reflect the in-app purchase previously made.  To do that I needed to find a way of determining the in-app purchase identifier.  Enough of all the talk, the magic [var identifier....] code to insert is as follows and goes into the section of your code where you detect the condition of SKPaymentQueue .restored:

case .restored:

```
                var identifier : NSString = transaction.payment.productIdentifier as NSString
                print("Restore identifier is \(identifier)")
            
                UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: myProductID)
            
                SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction)
```